# Get a list of all function parameters from inside the function

Tags: r

Is there a way to get *all* function parameters from within a function?

`match.call()` doesn't return parameters with defaults set but not overridden. For example:

```
xf <- function (a, b="Hi", c=TRUE) {
  print(as.list(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)))
}

>xf(3)
[[1]]
xf

$a
[1] 3
```

I am writing a package with a function that calls an existing function, but I want to be able to set defaults that are not on the existing function. (I was planning on using the list from `match.call`, passing it into the other function with `do.call` and returning the result.

**Update:** An interesting issue that relates to S3 methods. I created a new S3 method, and used @Ferdinand.kraft's answer. `as.list(environment(), all.names=TRUE)` The all.names argument keeps names starting with a `.` in the list. It turns out the the method dispatch adds several arguments to the function environment, including `.Generic` `.Class` `.Method` and several others. This could cause problems if you pass these on to the function in `do.call`. One of the other answers may be a better all around solution, but I like the simplicity of `as.list(environment())`.

Comment: does `args` do what you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also return the environment at the beginning of the function:

```
xf <- function (a, b="Hi", c=TRUE) {
  as.list(environment(), all=TRUE)
}
```

Result:

```
> xf(a=1)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "Hi"

$c
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Me too. :-) And it can get even simplier if no argument name begins with a dot - or if you don't want to pass them along - in that case you can drop the parameter `all=TRUE`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ls` and `mget`. `ls` will (by default), list the objects in the calling frame (in this case, within the function), `mget` will get these.

eg

```
xf <- function(a,b='Hi',c){
  # this gets the current definitions of `a`, `b`, and `c` 
  incall <-mget(ls())
  incall}

 xf(3)
## $a
## [1] 3
## 
## $b
## [1] "Hi"
##
## $c
```

You can then use `do.call(whatever, incall)`