# How to get a list with the arguments being used by a function?

Tags: r

I want to get a list of the arguments being used in `my_fun` excluding the dots and the first argument. I also want to have the default values of the optional arguments. This is how I'm currently doing it, but I'm sure there is a simpler way:

```
my_fun <- function(a, b = "b", c = "c", d = c("d1","d2"), ...){
    my_call <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE))[-1]
    my_call[names(my_call) %in% c("a","...")] <- NULL

    my_formals <- as.list(formals("my_fun"))
    my_formals[names(my_formals) %in% c("a","...")] <- NULL
    for (arg in names(my_call)){
        my_formals[[arg]] <- my_call[[arg]]
    }
    my_formals$d <- eval(my_formals$d)
    my_formals
}

res <- my_fun("a", c = 3, e = 3, f = 5)
res
# list(b = "b", c = 3, d = c("d1","d2"))
```

Note that because I'm using `formals` I have to do an awkward `eval`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a few people want a way to construct a list loaded with everything: positional, named, and `...` arguments. I'm sure there must be edge cases, but this may be a moderately reusable solution:

```
expand.args <- function() {
  named_args <- as.list(parent.frame())
  dot_args <- as.list(substitute(list(...), parent.frame()))[-1L]
  c(named_args, dot_args)
}
```

In your case (where you want to drop the first argument) you could do:

```
my_fun <- function(a, b = "b", c = "c", d = c("d1", "d2"), ...) {
  my_args <- expand.args()[-1L]
  return(my_args)  
}

my_fun("a", 3, x = "woot")
```

Hat tip to:

- [Get a list of all function parameters from inside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891459)
- [match.call with default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397364)