# R Test parmeters of functions passed to a function before evaluation

Tags: r, function, arguments

I want to construct a function (let's call it f()) that will get as arguments two 
other functions (f1(),f2()). Both f1 and f2 get arguments of their own.
I want f(), prior to evaluating f1() and f2(), to make some test on the arguments passed 
to f1() and f2(), for example, verify that their names are identical. 
In short, I want something like this:

```
f<-function(f1(param),f2(param)){
f1Param<-#get the param argument of f1
f2Param<-#get the param argument of f2
stopifnot(identical(names(f1Param),names(f2Param)))
#evaluate f1(param) and f2(param) and do some opertaions on the outputs
}
```

But I'm not sure how I can extract the arguments from f1() and f2() and then get them 
evaluated.
I saw some suggestions to resolve this with [match.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885207/get-all-parameters-as-list?rq=1) 
or [mget()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891459/get-a-list-of-all-function-parameters-from-inside-the-function).
However in the examples given there, the only thing the called function does is to return its argument,
I actually want my functions to do something.
Is there any way to use say, match.call() to test the parameters in the environment of
the calling function (f() in my example), and then decided if to evaluate f1 and f2 based
on the result of the test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case you'd better modify your f() to accept 4 args, the two functions and their respective args (as a list). If it's not possible I see no way to achieve that as the function call being lazy evaluated, you can't really access them before the function call itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Tensibai's suggesttion you can do something like:

```
f <- function(f1, f2, f1Param, f2Param){
  stopifnot(is.list(f1Param) && is.list(f2Param))
  stopifnot(identical(names(f1Param),names(f2Param)))
  do.call(f1, f1Param) == do.call(f2, f2Param)
}
```

An Example would be:

```
> f(mean, mean, list(x = 1:10), list(x = 2:9))
[1] TRUE
> f(mean, mean, list(x = 1:10), list(y = 2:9))
# ERROR
```